# Слово "отравлена"

Tags: фонетика

"Отравлена". Где-то услышал ударение в этом слове на последний слог. Правильное ли оно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. В данном слове ударение не переходит на окончание: ОтрАвленный, отрАвлена. Но подобные: отраженА, отращенА